# Remove duplicated record from list of dict by key, but preserve one with most keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Problem is i have list of dictionaries for example:

```
lst = [{"a": "AA", "b": "BB"}, 
        {"a": "ok", "b": "ok"}, 
        {"a": "AA", "b": "BB", "c": "CC"}]
```

Those two records are duplicates (key "a" have same value):

```
  [{"a": "AA", "b": "BB"},
  {"a": "AA", "b": "BB", "c": "CC"}]
```

I tried

```
duplicated = set()
records_output =\
    [x for x in lst if [(x["a"]) not in duplicated, duplicated.add((x["a"]))][0]]
```

It removes one with most keys, but i want to remove one with lesser keys so i get

```
[{"a": "ok", "b": "ok"},
{"a": "AA", "b": "BB", "c": "CC"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this problem.

*records are input*

```
    # all str/int values found by key
    values = [r[key_name] for r in records]

    # duplicated values
    duplicates = [val for val, count in Counter(values).items() if count > 1]

    # iterate over each value
    for val in duplicates:

        duplicated_temp = []

        # finding all records with provided key/value
        for r in records:
            if(r[key_name] == val):
                duplicated_temp.append(r)

        # finding record with most key
        record_to_preserve = duplicated_temp[0]
        for dup in duplicated_temp:
            if(len(dup.keys()) > len(record_to_preserve.keys())):
                record_to_preserve = dup

        # iterate over duplicated
        # remove all from records except one with most keys
        for r in duplicated_temp:
            if(r != record_to_preserve):
                records.remove(r)

    return records
```